# How do you change the fill color of a copy of a dynamic symbol in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a dynamic symbol and I want to change its fill color.  Tutorials online show it being very easy: select the symbol, select a fill.

I found another question here where it wasn't working for the person, and the answer was to use a very specific black: [dynamic symbols color change](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105817/dynamic-symbols-color-change)

I tried using the correct black, but that didn't work either.  Below I have some screeshots.  You can see that:

1. All symbols I've made are dynamic (have the + sign)
2. "Pine Corner" layer is a symbol.
3. The appearance area of the "Properties Pane" shows details on the group it is part of instead of the selected layer
4. The "Appearance Pane" shows that Pine Corner is a symbol, but gives no access to changing the fill or stroke.

**What am I missing here?  How do you change the fill color of a copy of a dynamic symbol in Illustrator?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Try this. Use the direct selection tool (A) - black arrow, to select an object in the symbol.  In the appearance panel click on the fill square, hit the little arrow dropdown to the side, and choose a new colour from the dropdown.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!